# Query last value in Flux

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

I'm trying to get the last value from some IoT sensors and I actually achieved an intermediary result with the following Flux query:

```
from(bucket:"mqtt-bucket")
|> range(start:-10m )
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "mqtt_consumer")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["thingy"] == "things/green-1/shadow/update"
                  or r["thingy"] == "things/green-3/shadow/update" 
                  or r["thingy"] == "things/green-2/shadow/update")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "data")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["appId"] == "TEMP" or r["appId"] == "HUMID")
|> toFloat()
|> last()
```

**The problem:** I would like to get the last mesured value independently of a time range.
I saw in the docs that there is no way to unbound the range function. Maybe there is a work around ?

Answer (score 4):

I just found this:

```
from(bucket: "stockdata")
  |> range(start: 0)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "nasdaq")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["symbol"] == "OPEC/ORB")
  |> last()
```